# Showing that the law of a random vector is continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to learn about random vectors by solving some exercise. I don't know how this is done. I would appreciate it if someone could write a rigorous proof for this.

Let $X$ be a centred Gaussian vector and with $\Sigma_X$ being its symmetric $d\times d$ covariance matrix. And let $r$ be the rank of the covariance matrix, then we can write it as $\sum_{i=1}^r Y_i e_i $ where $Y_1,\ldots,Y_r$ are independent centred Gaussian random variables and $e_1,\ldots,e_d$ are the basis of $\mathbb R^d$ in which the covariance matrix is diagonal.

I want to show that the law of $X$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$ if and only if $r=d$ and that for the density of $X$, we have $$P_X(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2} \sqrt{\det(\Sigma_X)}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \langle x, \Sigma_X^{-1} x \rangle\right)$$

For the forward direction, I know that the density is simply the Radon-Nikodym derivative. But, I don't know how to show that it's only the case when $r=d$.
For the Backward direction, I'm really not sure how to go with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $r<d$. Then, the law of $X$ is supported on the proper subspace $\textrm{span}\{e_j\}_{1\leq r\leq d}$. However, any proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a Lesbegue null-set. Thus, the law of $X$ cannot be absolutely continuous with respect to the Lesbegue measure.

Comment: Ok, You've shown that for r<d, the law is not absolutely continuous. But, how do you show that it actually is absolutely continuous when r=d?

Comment: @Jack You seemed to only have doubts about how to treat the case when $r<d$. When $r=d$, Then, the joint distribution of the $Y$'s clearly has density (being the simultaneous distribution of $n$ independent variables with density) and $X$ is an invertible linear transformation of the $Y$-vector. Hence, by the Jacobi transformation theorem, the distribution of $X$ will have density.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I get that the X has density. But, I have some trouble understanding why the distribution of X is singular. I mean both these conditions have to be shown in order to prove that the distribution is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $R^n$.  P.S. The density I gave follows from it being the Radon-Nikodyn derivative right? And also I would also really appreciate if you could tell me how the backwards direction goes.

Comment: Being absolutely continuous just means having a density. So for the backwards direction, the support of any Gaussian measure with density must, by the previous points, have support on all of the space. Hence, $r=d$. (if the support were some proper subspace, you could pick $r<d$ and get, by the above, that the distribution does not admit a density).

Answer (score 1):

If $r<d$ then $\Sigma$ is singular. There exist constants $c_i$ not all $0$ such that $\sum c_i EX_iX_j=0$ for all $j$. Multiply by $c_j$ and sum over $j$ to see that $E(\sum c_ix_i)^{2}=0$. Thus $\sum c_i x_i=0$ a.s.. But the the joint distribution is supported by the subspace $\{(x_i): \sum c_ix_i=0\}$ and this subspace has Lebesgue measure $0$. This shows that the joint distribution of the $X_i$'s is singular w.r.t. Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm a little confused. Ok, I understand that showing that the distribution of $X$ is singular and having a density implies that the distribution  is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Some follow-ups to actually understand your proof. 1) Why exactly is $\sum E(X_i X_j) = 0 $ for all j? 2) How do you go from $\sum_{over j} \sum c_i c_j E(X_i X_j) to E(\sum c_i x_i)^2 = 0$ ? The rest is clear. P.S how would you show the backwards direction?

Comment: 1):I am using the fact that the columns of the matrix are linearly dependent. 2): Just expand $(\sum c_i x_j)^{2}$.